# CI build is getting stuck after executing gradlew build but when i kill the GradleWrapperMain or GradleDaemon process then build is going through fine

Tags: gradle

CI build is getting stuck after executing gradlew build command. As you can see in the below logs the build is getting successfully executed and the daemon which executed the build is getting stopped as well but after that the build is getting stuck for infinite time until it time outs. we are using java 11.0.17, spring boot 2.x and gradle wrapper 7.6

**Below is the CI build logs in debug mode**

```
2023-06-28T11:38:17.325+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 12, disk reads: 6 (avg: 0.002 secs, total: 0.017 secs)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.325+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 8 resolution results binary files in 0.002 secs
2023-06-28T11:38:17.325+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
2023-06-28T11:38:17.325+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Run build' completed
2023-06-28T11:38:17.325+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 3: released lock on worker lease
2023-06-28T11:38:17.326+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonClientsManager] Stopping 1 worker daemon(s).
2023-06-28T11:38:17.328+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker] Completed Gradle Worker Daemon 2.
2023-06-28T11:38:17.350+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
2023-06-28T11:38:17.350+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 2' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.352+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonClientsManager] Stopped 1 worker daemon(s).
2023-06-28T11:38:17.352+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
2023-06-28T11:38:17.352+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
2023-06-28T11:38:17.352+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for checksums cache (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/checksums)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache sha1-checksums.bin (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/checksums/sha1-checksums.bin)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on checksums cache (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/checksums).
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/fileHashes)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache resourceHashesCache.bin (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/fileHashes/resourceHashesCache.bin)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.353+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/fileHashes).
2023-06-28T11:38:17.354+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS Checkout Cache (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
2023-06-28T11:38:17.354+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache VCS metadata (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/vcsMetadata) was closed 0 times.
2023-06-28T11:38:17.354+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for dependencies-accessors (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/dependencies-accessors)
2023-06-28T11:38:17.354+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on dependencies-accessors (/home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle/7.6/dependencies-accessors).
2023-06-28T11:38:17.354+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.VersionSpecificCacheCleanupAction] Processed version-specific caches at /home/jenkins/workspace/zation_priority_CP-2459_sb2_test/com-manh-cp-organization/.gradle for cleanup in 0.0 secs
2023-06-28T11:38:17.365+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:23.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:33.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:43.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:38:53.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2023-06-28T11:39:03.434+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

**NOTE:**
CI build is not going through and our process of migrating to java 11, spring boot 2.x and gradle 7.6 is getting hampered.

I have already gone through gradle documentation, tried many google search but still nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use some CI that is monitoring started processes and does not end the CI job if a process started by the job is still running instead of ending the CI job after the Gradle build finished?

If so, you maybe need to run your build with `--no-daemon` which causes the daemon to not be preserved after the build finished, but end the daemon process gracefully.

Comment: hello,i am running the following command ./gradlew build -PpackagingType=war -x test -x check. after executing the command successfully the daemon which executed the build process also getting stopped gracefully but after that build is getting stuck. i tried ./gradlew build -PpackagingType=war -x test -x check  --no-daemon but still it didnt help me. 


https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/25538

please check the above github link for the thread dump mentioned in the comment section

Comment: You contradict yourself. You say the daemon is stopped after the build but then you say it is still running and you could take a thread dump. Those two are the opposite of each other.

Comment: if you see the initial logs attached above the daemon is getting stopped successfully after that the build is getting stuck

Comment: No, I don't see that

Comment: below logs talks about successfully completing the build and daemon is getting exited successfully
Stopping 1 worker daemon(s).
Completed Gradle Worker Daemon 2.
Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 2' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
Stopped 1 worker daemon(s).
Stopping 0 deployment handles
The daemon has finished executing the build.

and then build is going on for ever with below logs 
Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

Comment: when I delete the GradleWrapperMain process the build is going through

Comment: "worker daemon" != "Gradle daemon". One of the worker daemons finished, that's correct, but that is not "the daemon executing the build". As you can see from the logs after that, the Gradle daemon is still running and periodically locks the daemon address registry, does some maintenance work and releases the lock again. This is absolutely normal behavior for the Gradle daemon after it finished executing a build and waiting for the next to be executed. If this also comes with `--no-daemon`, something is majorly wrong as with `--no-daemon` the daemon would be gracefully quit after success.

Comment: Just for the sake of closing this discussion and clarity . my issue has been resolved. it was a issue with the shell script. we have a loop which was causing the issue. not sure though how come it was working for lesser versions of gradle or it has anything to do with gradle version upgradation, not sure. Thanks Vampire for your quick response and guidance.